# How to drop rows or change values based on datetime index from the same time every day?

Tags: pandas, time-series, data-cleaning

I searched but couldn't find an answer to this:

I have a dataset with erroneous data recorded twice a day, but at the same time every day.

The data point at 1300 needs to be zeroed out to preserve data integrity.

The data point at 1930 needs to be removed from the dataset entirely.

I did this successfully with a loop, but it takes forever.

Comment: I don't know hoe to fix that your data is erroneous. Therefor you have to provide more information. An example Dataframe, and what ouput you expect. For the other two things i tried to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if 1300/1930 is the index or the position in the dataset. They don't have to match always.

In case it's the index:

```
df.loc[1300].values[:] = 0
df.drop(index=[1930], inplace=True)
```

In case it's the postion within the dataset:

```
df.iloc[1300].values[:] = 0
df.drop(index=df.index[1930], inplace=True)
```

Comment: Yes, the index is a DateTime index.  Example format is < 2015-01-06 13:30:00 >.  My issue is referencing the time when the index is DateTime with date and time stored in the same value

Comment: Can you please provide an example dataframe. Means 1930 a time? Do you want to  change the data at a specific time every day? And if the data is recored twice a day and you want to drop the data 19:30 and zero the data at 13:00, wouldn't you get a dataframe with only zeros. You see without a example it is very hard to understand what you mean.